# Unable to map angular UI with spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Dispatcher:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nt.beans" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value></value>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {//Serves main index.html

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "/";
    }
}
```

UI-Router:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /login
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Login");

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
            .state('Login', {
                url: "/Login",
                views: {
                    header: header,
                    content: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/Login.html',
                        controller: function () {
                        }
                    },
                    footer: footer
                }
            });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: false,
        requireBase: true
    });
});
```

index jsp page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>BulkSMS - HTML</title>
        <base href="/BulkSMS2/"> 

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="resources/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <!--font-awesome-->
        <link href="resources/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <!--Bootstrap social-->
        <link href="resources/bower_components/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrap">

            <!--main content-->
            <div ui-view="content"></div>

        </div>   

        <!--Bootstrap core JavaScript--> 
        <script src="resources/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!--angular related scripts-->
        <script src="resources/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="resources/bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="resources/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="resources/js/angular_module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="resources/js/controllers/StateProvider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="resources/js/controllers/LoginController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the app, it is supposed to load login.html but it showing error in console like:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8084/BulkSMS2/resources/bower_components/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css"`

The prefix in dispatcher.xml is `WEB-INF/views` so the login.html page inside it should load and also in the controller I am returning the path as `/` so any unmatched url pattern should load login page according to state provider.